# Streaming outputs to another window without running the same commands again on iterm2

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, zsh, iterm2

First of all, I think every command running consumes some resources.

So if I'd like to have another window displaying the same output of the same commands being run on another session without running the same commands again ( the reason of such need is I am switching between desktops a lot on macOS )

Is it possible to accomplish it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### General observation

I don't use macOS and I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "switching between desktops". In KDE Plasma I can set my terminal emulator window (or basically any window) to be displayed on all *virtual* desktops. I don't know if you can do it in macOS.

From the point of view of consumed resources this should be the best because it would show you not only the same commands and the same shell, but also the same terminal emulator. If I were you, I would first try to solve the problem this way.

---

#### Specific solution: tmux

As an alternative use tmux and attach to the same tmux session from as many terminals (terminal emulators) as you want. By default sole `tmux` creates a new session; `tmux attach-session` attaches to the most recently used (preferably unattached) session and the shortest alias is `tmux a`. So if you want to work with one tmux session only then

```
tmux a || tmux
```

is your universal command. Run it in many terminals (terminal emulators) and enjoy having access to the same instance(s) of your shell from everywhere. You need to do this as a certain user though. (I think sharing a tmux server between users is possible but it requires effort; using `tmux` as a certain user is straightforward. If your "switching between desktops" does not imply switching between users then the method should simply work.)

Notes:

- In tmux there are few more sophisticated ways to share the same "view", see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1489266/432690) or [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1606555/432690).
- Tmux has more advantages ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1398118/432690)).